# Tracking special day in google analytic

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I need to tracking special day in google analytic, e.g.: the delivery date of my web app.

Is possible?

Carlo

Comment: To track you mean to have it 'saved' in analytics interface? Or for every one of your web app users, to be able to tell the date they for example 'received' your web app ?

Comment: Yes, i want save a generic date in analytics interface.
E.g. today i delivery new release of my web app and i want track this date in Analytics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it's not related to coding, and it's also a little open-ended and unclear.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you have installed GA in your web app and launched with it, it will automatically track every day even seconds of it. What you need to do is create a custom report of that very day/date you want.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need is a really useful feature of the Analytics interface called 'annotations'. Here is a really [good guide](https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/back-to-basics-google-analytics-annotations-simple-useful-feature) on how to do them and some use cases. Basically under the graphs of each section you can add a 'note' for your own reference.